# Get value of DIV,CSS value - WebDriver (Selenium 2) - JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Hi i have this html code:

```
<div id="idvalue" value="56"></div>
```

And i want to get the value '56'. How can i do that? I tried this but it returns null.

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("idvalue")).getAttribute("value"));
```

I am using Selenium 2
Please help..

Comment: Try `System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("idvalue")).getText());`

Comment: That returns what is inside div tag. If i have:   

`<div id="idvalue" value="56">test</div>`

it returns "test"

Comment: Are you sure you have only one element with `id="idvalue"`

Comment: Yes i am sure of that.

Comment: @LuisCarlos Try `System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("idvalue")).getCssValue("value"));`

Comment: Now it returns "" i.e. nothing.

Comment: what does this print. System.out.println(driver.findElements("idvalue").size());

Answer (score 3):

`value` is no valid attribute for the `div` element. You shouldn't be surprised that this does not work...

Comment: Yes, but afaik, they need to start with "data-". And even then, I don't know if selenium2 supports that...

Answer (score 1):

did you tried this way

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object val=js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('idvalue').getAttribute('value');");

System.out.println("Value attr value: " + val);
```

output: Value attr value: 56

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i found that this number i have to retrive i finded in another div like this way: `<div id="idvalue">56</div>`
And that is simple.